# How do I swap the function and multimedia presses on the fn keys?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bios, windows-10-v1607

I know that I have to get to the advanced BIOS settings but how, specifically, do I do this?

I have a Windows 10 64-bit, HP Pavilion Notebook with a F.52 BIOS

Comment: If it's Logitech, there's a toggle in the control panel

Comment: I'm neither psychic or a mind reader so I can't tell what make and model of computer and what BIOS you have. Please [edit] your question to include that important information.

Comment: Ok, done. It's a F.52 BIOS